# Wrong spacing after equation environment when using `setspace` package

Tags: vertical-spacing, setspace

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\lineskip}{2em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation*}
    a + b + \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

The spacing before and after the equation is inconsistent.

Comment: setting `\lineskip` is a rather odd thing to do in a document, what is the intention of `\setlength{\lineskip}{2em}` ? `\lineskip` is only used in error recovery situations where normal baseline spacing can not be achieved and it is normally _very_ small.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my document I'd like to have larger space around equations when, for example, large operators are typed. Here setting it to 2em is just for illustration.

Comment: but `\lineskip` is an "emergency" setting: you are saying if you have an inline fraction that makes a line slightly taller than the baseline space, add an additional 2em (!!!!) between lines of the paragraph just before the tall entry, leavig other lines in the paragraph with standard space.

Comment: did you intend to set `\abovedisplayskip` ? I have used latex for over 30 years and don't think I have ever set `\lineskip` in a document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My intention was indeed to set `\lineskip`. I think the default `\abovedisplayskip` is too large when the equation is of low height, so I decreased `\abovedisplayskip`. Then I found the space is not large enough when there are big symbols in the equation, so I decided to change `\lineskip`. Here 2em is just for emphasizing the inconsistency before and after the equation. However as you said this is not a good practice so I will not change this.

Comment: I added an example of the effect of `\lineskip` to my answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You almost certainly want to set the display skips not `\lineskip`, and you need to delay the settings until after `setspace` settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% No!!!\setlength{\lineskip}{2em}

\AtBeginDocument{
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2em plus .2em minus .2em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{1em plus .2em minus .2em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2em plus .2em minus .2em}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{1.5em plus .2em minus .2em}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation*}
    a + b + \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

---

`\lineskip` is not directly related to equations and setting it makes a line that is slightly too big suddenly generate massive space, see the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One {\large \^X}xxx 
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\setlength\lineskip{2em}

One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One {\large \^X}xxx 
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.
One two three four five six seven eight.

\end{document}
```